# How to validate only text content (no tags) in Firestore rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, re2

I'm trying to validate user posts content by stripe tags in UI and at firestore rules too, pattern works fine in UI, but in firestore rules how to validate post content and allow only texts and striping all tags?

A snippet code of my firestore rules:

```js
{
  allow write: if (request.resource.data.content.matches("<[^>]*>/g") == request.resource.data.content)
}
```

I've checked https://github.com/google/re2 but I couldn't figured out how to add a global flag to my pattern. What do I miss?

Comment: As you can see in their [syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) page, there is no `/g` flag in re2. I suggest that you read this [blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2021/01/code-review-security-rules.html).

Comment: Thanks @Dondi I can see that but I don't understand the alternative way to match expressions globally, I need to strip tags using a pattern, How to achieve that ?